# Declaring location of highchart bars on a chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have highchart and which looks like this ;[if i commented out max value of xAxis i see this image below ]

[image]

Here is the similar jsfiddle ;

[Jsfiddle Link for similar case](http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/3/)

I want to push the bars to all the way left side of the chart.

I actually can do it using hard coded json value on max: of xAxis . but my json value depends on `year+month+day+hours+min+sec.` so when some of the values here are changed , then i have to change the hard coded value to something else so it is not logical .

If there is anyway using a max value dynamically  Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what is wrong with your jsfiddle :) Could you show what is expected result? Or in jsFiddle add `start_chart_scale_dt` and `end_chart_scale_dt` variables, so we can see expected min/max.

Comment: if you check jsfiddle , you ll see  the last bar belongs to sp_est_pop_mars_indx. And in arraylist it has from and to .so for the end json value for this yAxis variable is : 60550000. if you increase this value to 80550000 and use it as  max: 80550000, it push the bars to left.

Comment: this is how you can achieve using hard code value , but i want to achieve this dynamically .

Comment: Have you tried to use `maxPadding` ? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/13/

Comment: Thats probably what i want .How it works , i  mean what does it do ?

Comment: Check [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to increase `maxPadding`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/13/).

More info about `maxPadding` in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding):

> Padding of the max value relative to the length of the axis. A padding of 0.05 will make a 100px axis 5px longer. This is useful when you don't want the highest data value to appear on the edge of the plot area. When the axis' max option is set or a max extreme is set using axis.setExtremes(), the maxPadding will be ignored. Defaults to 0.01.